# This code overrides the result of the loops. How to avoid that action?

Tags: javascript

This javascript game code generates two lines of information one is the number of guessing and the second features a comparison about the guess if it is greater or less than the number entered in the prompt window. Each set of guess is numbered in how many guesses have been made. What I want to accomplish is that the guesses need to remain on the screen in a one column at the end of each game but this code as it’s written overrides the number of guessing. My question is how to avoid the override issue? Below is the code any input on how to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
    <body>

        <h3>JavaScript Guessing Game</h3>

        <p>Welcome to the guessing game. I'll pick up the number between 1 and 100 and you try to guess
        what it is. You Get 7 tries.<p>

        <p id="guess"></p>
        <p id="guessed"></p>
        <p id="small"></p>
        <p id="big"></p>
        <p id="times"></p>

</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        number = Math.round((Math.random() * 999))+ 1;


            counter = 0;
            do
                {
                counter++;

                guess = prompt("What's your guess?");
                document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = ("Guess #"+counter+" was "+guess );
                /*document.write*/

                if (guess == number) {
                    /*document.write("You guessed it!<BR>");*/
                    document.getElementById("guessed").innerHTML = ("You guessed it! You Won!");
                    }
                else  {
                    if (guess < number)  {
                        /*document.write("Too small, guess again.<BR>");*/
                        document.getElementById("small").innerHTML = ("Too small, guess again.");
                        }
                    else  {
                        /*document.write("Too big, guess again.<BR>");*/
                        document.getElementById("big").innerHTML = ("Too big, guess again.");
                        }
                    }


                } while (counter <7 && guess != number);

            if (guess != number) {
                    document.getElementById("times").innerHTML = ("I won in 7 times - the number was " + number);
                    }

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want the result to stick or the numbers that were guessed?

Comment: I would like that the numbers that were guessed remain on the screen. By the way you solution is awesome. The only thing that was left, again, the numbers still on the screen.

Comment: add  @joel's answer as well

Answer (score 1):

append instead of replacing

```
document.getElementById("times").innerHTML = (document.getElementById("times").innerHTML + "<br>I won in 7 times - the number was " + number);
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6qv1ru0/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next instead of replacing.

```
document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML += ("Guess #"+counter+" was "+guess +"<br/>");
```